# PHP selectmenu error displaying arrays values

Tags: php, mysql

Please excuse the newbie question but ive only recently started with PHP. Ive been stuck with this for the past hour.

Im pulling playernames and positons from a table in my db
I then use a for each loop to extract the data which was assigned to an array.
Inside the foreach loop i have an option tag with the variable

When I execute the script im expecting to see the playernames relevant to the different positions in the selectmenu. But Im getting some strange error as you can see by the image.

[image]

My code follows:

```
include 'connect.php';
$position = array("THP", "HKR", "LHP", "LK4", "LK5", "FL6", "FL7", "NR8", "SH", "FH");
var_dump($position);
$size = sizeof($position);
    for($i=0; $size > $i; $i++)
    {
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT `player_id`, `name`, `surname`, `position` 
                    FROM `player_info` 
                    WHERE `position` = '$position[$i]'") 
                    or die(mysql_error());
var_dump($position[$i]);
              while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
              {
                  $playername =  $row['name'];
                  $player_lastname = $row['surname'];
                  $player_position = $row['position'];    
              }
    var_dump($playername);
echo'<form name="teamselect" method="post">';
     print $position[$i];
    echo'<select name="team">';
        foreach($playername as $name)
        {   
            echo '<option value="'.$name.'">'.$name.'</option>';            
        }
        echo'</select>';
        echo'</form>';
unset($name);
    }
```

If anyone could point me in the right directions it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much in advance

*P.S I realize my code is very vulnerable to sql injections. I will address the problem when I start learning about it*

Comment: I don't see any errors anywhere? That's the output of `var_dump()`.

Comment: yes it is the output of var_dump()

Comment: So, what's strange about it?

Comment: Well as you can see the selectmenus are not displaying the data correctly

Comment: Remove print $position[$i]; and post the result. It seems $playername is not an array.

Comment: @bksi still the same problem

Comment: use $playername[] = $row['name'] instead $playername=$row['name']

Comment: @bksi thank you so much!! If you answer the question with above comment ^^ ill give you best answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you iterate twice same data. Try this:

```
include 'connect.php';
$position = array("THP", "HKR", "LHP", "LK4", "LK5", "FL6", "FL7", "NR8", "SH", "FH");
var_dump($position);
$size = sizeof($position);
echo'<form name="teamselect" method="post">';
    for($i=0; $size > $i; $i++)
    {
        echo'<select name="team[]">';
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT `player_id`, `name`, `surname`, `position` 
                    FROM `player_info` 
                    WHERE `position` = '$position[$i]'") 
                    or die(mysql_error());
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo '<option value="'.$row['name'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
            /*$playername =  $row['name'];
              $player_lastname = $row['surname'];
              $player_position = $row['position'];  */  
        }
        echo'</select>';
    }
echo'</form>';
```

**Note "select name="team[]". This will send you all the selects as array in $_POST['team']**